# Having trouble connecting to server using SQL Alchemy and pymssql

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I want to automate some SQL queries to save time, so I tried using SQL Alchemy to connect to the server.

```
conn = create_engine("mssql+pymssql:/<user>:<pass>@<address>/<database>")
query = pd.read_sql_query(<query>)
```

This gave me an unknown connection error, so I looked around and found pymssql

```
db= pymssql.connect(host=address, user=user, password=pass, database=db, port=1433)
```

I am now getting this error:

OperationalError: (20009), d'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (address:1433)\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10060)\n'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `pd.read_sql_query("SELECT ...", conn)`

Comment: yeah, I made a typo in my question. When I use what you suggested, I get: InterfaceError: (pymssql.InterfaceError) Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.

Comment: Does the server you are using require an encrypted connection (for example, Azure SQL)?

Comment: I know that I need to be connected to our VPN in order to access it. I was wondering if that would complicate things